# Maximum number of records for a custom object in salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce

What is the maximum number of records within a single custom object in salesforce.com?

There does not seem to be a limit indicated in https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/limits.htm

But of course, there has to be a limit of some kind. EG: Could 250 million records be stored in a single salesforce.com custom object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the only limit is your data storage, you can see what you've used by going to Setup -> Administration Setup -> Data Management -> Storage Usage.

In one of the Orgs I work with I can see one object has almost 2GB of data for just under a million records, and this accounts for a little over a third of the storage available. Your storage space depends on your Salesforce Edition and number of users. [See here for details.](https://cs2.salesforce.com/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?loc=help&target=admin_monitorresources.htm&section=Organization_Setup)

Answer (score 5):

I've seen the performance issue as well, though after about 1-2M records the performance hit appears magically to plateau, or at least it didn't appear to significantly slow down between 1M and 10M. I wonder if orgs are tier-tuned based on volume... :/

But regardless of this, there are other challenges which make it less than ideal for big data. Even though they've increased the SOQL governor limit to permit up to 50 million records to be retrieved in one call, you're still strapped with a 200,000 line execution limit in Apex and a 10K DML limit (per execution thread). These can be bypassed through Batch Apex, yet this has limitations as well. You can only execute 250K batches in 24 hours and only have 5 batches running at any given time.

So... the moral of the story seems to be that even *if* you managed to get a billion records into a custom object, you really can't do much with the data at that scale anyway. Therefore, it's effectively *not* the right tool for that job in its current state.

2-cents

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Salesforce has what is called [Big Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object.htm) which are designed for storing 100s of millions of records

Answer (score 2):

LaceySnr is correct. However, there is an inverse relationship between the number of records for an object and performance. Any part of the system that filters on that object will be impacted, such as views, reports, SOQL queries, etc.

It's hard to talk specific numbers since salesforce has upwards of a dozen server clusters, each with their own performance characteristics. And there's probably a lot of dynamic performance management that occurs regularly. But, in the past I've seen performance issues start to creep in around 2M records. One possible remedy is you can ask salesforce to index fields that you plan to filter on.

Comment: A lot depends on exactly what you want to do, especially WRT to reporting and sharing config.

Comment: So, basically, salesforce.com would be inappropriate for any 'big data' or heavy-duty web apps, given the data storage/performance constraints?

Comment: At its core, salesforce is a highly customizable CRM system. Salesforce certainly has lots of hardware, but I doubt it's tuned for big data, nor does it support typical tooling for big data applications. Right tool for the job, ya know?